# Rails grouping data to an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two objects Maths and Science. I'm trying to add some modules based on the courses. For example if I add Core Algebra it should bind to Maths Object. So I can display all the Maths modules under Maths heading and Science modules under Science heading dynamically. At the moment module.name just displays the all the modules but doesn't bind to either of them.

```
  = link_to 'Science', modules_path
  = link_to 'Maths', modules_path

- @modules.each do |module|
  %li
    = link_to module.name

= link_to 'Add', new_module_path, class: 'btn btn-info'
```

I added the following in the database so I have two at the moment. Similarly I want to add them from the browser.

```
Science.find_or_create_by_name "Cell and molecular Biology"
Maths.find_or_create_by_name "Core Algebra"
```

Modules controller:

```
Class ModulesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @modules = Module.all
  end

  def new
    @module = Module.new
  end

  def create
    @module = Module.new(params[:module])
    if @module.save
      redirect_to modules_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Models:

```
class Module < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  def science?
    self.is_a? Science
  end

  def maths?
    self.is_a? Maths
  end
end

class Science < Module; end
class Maths < Module; end
```

Comment: Provide your schema.rb, no information about associations here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to rethink how you model your data. Rather than Science and Math inheriting from Module, make a one-to-many association or a many-to-many association between ModuleGroup and Module, then you can get all module instances that belong to the 'math' module_group. e.g.

```
class ModuleGroup
  has_many :modules

  def self.maths_modules
    where(name: 'math')
  end
end

class Module
  belongs_to :module_group
end
```

Its a 'dryer' approach which will allow you to easily add new ModuleGroups.

As an aside, module as a class name may get confusing as 'Module' is a reserved word in ruby.